# Getting field value in elastic search plugin against document returned by result

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

My requirement is to search documents from elasticsearch based on fuzzy matching and then 'rescore' the documents by comparing the value of the document and an input string for e.g. If the query is returning 3 documents (doc:1,2,3), then for comparing the constant value 'Star Wars', the comparison should be as:

```
doc:1, MovieName:"Star Wars" (compare ('Star Wars','Star Wars'))
doc:2, MovieName:"Starr Warz" (compare ('Star Wars','Starr Warz'))
doc:3, MovieName:"The Star Wars" (compare ('Star Wars','The Star Wars'))
```

I found the following elasticsearch rescore plugin example and implemented it to achieve the above.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.2/plugins/examples/rescore/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/example/rescore/ExampleRescoreBuilder.java

I am able to pass and access the input 'Star Wars' in the plugin, however I am facing trouble getting the value of the MovieName field of the documents returned in the results (topdocs).

My Query:

```
  GET movie-idx/_search?
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "MovieName"
                ],
                "query": "Star Wars",
                "minimum_should_match": "61%",
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "_name": "fuzzy"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "rescore": {
        "calculateMovieScore": {
          "MovieName": "Star Wars"
        }
      }
    }
```

And my rescorer class looks like:

```
private static class DocsRescorer implements Rescorer {
        private static final DocsRescorer INSTANCE = new DocsRescorer();

        @Override
        public TopDocs rescore(TopDocs topDocs, IndexSearcher searcher, RescoreContext rescoreContext) throws IOException {
            DocRescoreContext context = (DocRescoreContext) rescoreContext;
            int end = Math.min(topDocs.scoreDocs.length, rescoreContext.getWindowSize());

            MovieScorer MovieScorer = new MovieScorerBuilder()
                    .withInputName(context.MovieName)
                    .build();

            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                String name = <get MovieName values from actual document returned by topdocs>
                float score = MovieScorer.calculateScore(name);
                topDocs.scoreDocs[i].score = score;
            }

            List<ScoreDoc> scoreDocList =  Stream.of(topDocs.scoreDocs).filter((a) -> a.score >= context.threshold).sorted(
                    (a, b) -> {
                        if (a.score > b.score) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        if (a.score < b.score) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        // Safe because doc ids >= 0
                        return a.doc - b.doc;
                    }
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
            ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = scoreDocList.toArray(new ScoreDoc[scoreDocList.size()]);
            topDocs.scoreDocs = scoreDocs;
            return topDocs;
        }

        @Override
        public Explanation explain(int topLevelDocId, IndexSearcher searcher, RescoreContext rescoreContext,
                                   Explanation sourceExplanation) throws IOException {
            DocRescoreContext context = (DocRescoreContext) rescoreContext;
            // Note that this is inaccurate because it ignores factor field
            return Explanation.match(context.factor, "test", singletonList(sourceExplanation));
        }

        @Override
        public void extractTerms(IndexSearcher searcher, RescoreContext rescoreContext, Set<Term> termsSet) {
            // Since we don't use queries there are no terms to extract.
        }
    }
```

My understanding is that the plugin code will execute once, it will get topdocs as results from the initial query (the fuzzy search in this case) and for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) will loop through each document returned in the result. The place where I need help is:

```
String name = <get MovieName value from actual document returned by topdocs>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been over 2 years, but i've ran into the same problem and found a solution so i'm posting it here. this was done for a Rescorer plugin in ES 7.8.0. the base example i used is the Grouping plugin [Link](https://github.com/anti-social/elasticsearch-rescore-grouping-mixup/blob/master/src/main/java/company/evo/elasticsearch/rescore/GroupingMixupRescorer.java).

It's a bunch of code that i don't fully understand, but the main principle is that you need an IFD (IndexFieldData<?>) instance of the field you want to get. in my example, i just needed _id of the hits. it looks like this:

1. prepare the IFD in advance and pass it to the RescoreContext: add a member to the class extending RescoreContext to keep this IFD on the context, lets call it "idField" (later used in section 3).

> ```
> @Override
> public RescoreContext innerBuildContext(int windowSize, QueryShardContext queryShardContext) throws IOException {
>     return new MyRescoreContext(windowSize, queryShardContext.getForField(queryShardContext.fieldMapper("_id")));
> }
> ```

2. next, in the Rescorer itself: (method rescore(...) )

2.1) first sort by scoreDoc.doc

```
 ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs; 
 Arrays.sort(hits, Comparator.comparingInt((d) -> d.doc));
```

2.2) PERFORM BLACK MAGIC (code i don't understand)

```
List<LeafReaderContext> readerContexts = searcher.getIndexReader().leaves();
int currentReaderIx = -1;
int currentReaderEndDoc = 0;
LeafReaderContext currentReaderContext = null;
    
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
ScoreDoc hit = hits[i];
    
    // find segment that contains current document 
   while (hit.doc >= currentReaderEndDoc) {  
      currentReaderIx++;
      currentReaderContext = readerContexts.get(currentReaderIx);
      currentReaderEndDoc = currentReaderContext.docBase + currentReaderContext.reader().maxDoc();
   }

   int docId = hit.doc - currentReaderContext.docBase;

   // code from section 3 goes here //
}
```

3. And now, with this magical "docId" in hand, you can fetch from the IFD inside the For loop:

   ```
    SortedBinaryDocValues values = rescoreContext.idField.load(currentReaderContext).getBytesValues();
    values.advanceExact(docId);
    String id = values.nextValue().utf8ToString();
   ```

in your case, instead of the _id field, get the IFD for the field you want, and create a Hashmap from docId -> string value inside the For loop.
then use this map in the same For loop where you apply the score.

hope this helps everybody! this technique is not documented at all and there are no explanations anywhere!